# hide or show HTML table rows using mobile jQuery

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

absolutely new to mobile development, very possible I'm missing something very basic.

We have a desktop site where we hide or show HTML table rows on a button click based on what class a  is.  The jQuery below is in a script file included in the display page:

HTML code:

```
<tr class="parentHeaderRow">
...
...
<tr class="parentHeaderRowHidden">
```

jQuery 1.7.1 script:

```
$('#rowHide').click (function() {
    $("tr.parentMetricRowHidden").css("display", "none");
    $("tr.childMetricRowHidden").css("display", "none");
    $("tr.grandchildMetricRowHidden").css("display", "none");
});
```

Click a button, remove or show the appropriate rows.

When trying to duplicate this hide/show row functionality in a mobile version, we run into an interesting issue.

On the initial page load, the code above will work.  But, once we make a selection and refresh the page with new data, say from territory down to district, the code does not work on the subsequent page load.  In fact, we do not see any events triggered by button clicks for these scripts.

Things we have tried:

- Change the declaration **FROM** $(document).ready(function(){ **TO** $(document).bind("pageinit", function(){
- Including the hide/shows scripts both inside and outside the
  $(document).bind function in the script file
- Including the show/hide scripts above in  tags in the display
  page
- Altered the  style and class both inline and via css

Any and all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please post a jsfiddle with your code.

Comment: have you tried $(document).on("click", "#rowHide", function(){...}); instead of $('#rowHide').click (function() {?

Comment: Basics of what I want to do @ JSFiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/n00bmobiledev/Pw6gp/  This works fine on a desktop, but refuses to work in mobile version after second page load.